# Creating binary from python scripts with pyinstaller for as many Linux distributions as possible

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller

Today I came a cross an issue with a binary I created from some python scripts using pyinstaller. I created the binary on fc17 but when I tried to run it on fc18 I got an error which was related to a difference in the openssl version on fc17 (1.0.0k) and fc18 (1.0.1e). This raises serious doubts about my ability to use pyinstaller since I don't know in advance on which Linux distributions my binary will end up. I'm willing to build the binary once every time I make a change in the python scripts but I can not afford having every possible Linux distribution and building the binary on every one of them. Is there a recipe to handle the variety of Linux distributions when building an application with pyinstaller?

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are looking for is [cx_freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/)

> cx_Freeze is a set of scripts and modules for freezing Python scripts
> into executables, in much the same way that py2exe and py2app do.
> Unlike these two tools, cx_Freeze is cross platform and should work on
> any platform that Python itself works on. It supports Python 2.3 or
> higher (including Python 3), since it makes use of the zip import
> facility which was introduced in 2.3.

Comment: This looks very interesting and certainly in the right direction of what I'm looking for. I'll give a try and accept your answer if indeed it will solve the issue I'm having.